# How to get all the test results in a single html file (index.html) in serenity BDD?

Tags: serenity-bdd, jbehave-maven-plugin

I have a serenity BDD framework which is up and running fine. I am getting the results in a html file (named randomly) separately for each scenario in target>site>serenity. Also I don't find any index.html file inside the folder.

I need a single html file where all the test results are displayed like we had in Thucydides [index.html] with dashboard and charts. can someone please help me to achieve this?????

This is how I am currently getting the reports

[image]

Comment: @JDelorean. can you pl help me on this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Thucydides, you need to run the aggregate task, e.g. `mvn serenity:aggregate` or `gradle aggregate`.